# Creating html tables with non-full inside borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm wondering if it's possible to create borders using html tables (not css tables) with non-full inside borders.

What I mean by this is, take for example this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wrL1790u/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC
        </td>
        <td>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC
        </td>
        <td>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

As you can see all the borders reach their full length.

Can you do something like this?

[image]

The reason it has to be `html` tables is because it is going to be sent as a html email and hence the CSS can't be too fancy to maximize client support over all the different email clients and follow those particular guidelines.

Comment: It's probably going to be easier to slice the borders up and do them as images if it's going to be sent as an HTML email.

Comment: @NickR Yeah, the other option was doing the whole area as images, but thought the more content the better to avoid spam filters by having too many images. But I suppose that is one idea. Thanks!

Comment: So it is sort of possible to do - http://jsfiddle.net/rc671tcp/ but it's a bit messy and not particularly flexible.

Comment: @NickR I agree, seems to be more trouble than it's worth. But I guess you can feel free to post it as an answer as it *does* do the job.